# Get all installed nuget dependencies via nuget.exe

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I'd like to read all installed dependencies via `nuget.exe` of a specific project / solution. I am aware, that this is working via `Get-Package` command via the NuGet Package Manager Console, but as i want to run this in a powershell command, i'd like to have access to it via nuget.exe directly.

`nuget list` only lists the available packages of a source, not of my dependencies.

Comment: You want get project dependencies from PS script via nuget?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation for latest recommended version `4.6.2` there isn't any information that it can be possible to list packages from solution or `appsettings.json`. You can use only Powershell interface.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference